# Change direction in stroke animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I want to revert the direction of a path drawing. So I changed fromValue and toValue propeties, but now full path is visible at the start of animation and it begins to disappear.
I have the path:

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(213.79, 170.83)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(131.93, 95) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(212.14, 128.68) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(176.13, 95)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 173.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(86.68, 95) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(50, 130.3)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(131.93, 252.7) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(50, 217.4) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(86.68, 252.7)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(157.55, 248.76) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(140.88, 252.7) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(149.49, 251.32)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.69, 281) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(166.59, 267.78) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(186.54, 281)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(267, 225.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(241.34, 281) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(267, 256.31)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(213.79, 170.83) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(267, 196.71) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(243.53, 172.86)];
    [bezierPath closePath];


    [color0 setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 11;
    [bezierPath stroke];
```

And the animation:

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.369 green: 0.42 blue: 0.475 alpha: 1];

    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [self bezierPath];


    CAShapeLayer *bezier = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    bezier.path          = bezierPath.CGPath;
    bezier.lineCap       = kCALineCapRound;
    bezier.strokeColor   = color.CGColor;
    bezier.fillColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    bezier.strokeStart   = 1.0;
    bezier.strokeEnd     = 0.0;
    bezier.lineWidth     = 8.0;
    bezier.strokeStart   = 0.0;
    bezier.strokeEnd     = 1.0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:bezier];

    if (animate)
    {
        CABasicAnimation *animateStrokeEnd = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        animateStrokeEnd.duration  = appDelegate.myPlayer.audioPlayer.duration;
        animateStrokeEnd.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        animateStrokeEnd.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        [bezier addAnimation:animateStrokeEnd forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were on the right track but you should have animated the `strokeStart` property instead.

Start with having both `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` as 1.0.

Then animate `strokeStart` **from** 1.0 **to** 0.0. This will give you the effect of the path being stroked from the end to the start.

For example when 25% of the path is stoked you will have strokeStart at 0.75 and strokeEnd at 1.0.